# Ocelot API Gateway Optional Parameter

Tags: asp.net-core, api-gateway, ocelot

Is there a way to tell Ocelot that a parameter is optional?

Let's say the query param below is optional:

```
"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/SearchAPI/?query={query}",
"DownstreamScheme": "https",
"DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": 5000
    }
],
"UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/SearchAPI/?query={query}",
"UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
"FileCacheOptions": {
    "TtlSeconds": 60
}
```

If I send a request to `/SearchAPI/?query=` I get a `404` as response. I need to duplicate the `Upstream` to not use the param to fix. Is there another way to fix that?

Comment: You just need to configure a path with no query string - /api/SearchAPI/ - then you can use with and without.

Comment: @tomredfern please, add as an answer so I can give you proper credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `{everything}` like

```
"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/SearchAPI/{everything}"
```

Comment: I had to create two different templates: one for `/XXX/dev/abp-api/api/identity/roles`, another one - for `/XXX/dev/abp-api/api/identity/roles/{any}` (or "everything" instead of "any", does not matter). Otherwise, my POST request for `/XXX/dev/abp-api/api/identity/roles` is not routed as ``/XXX/dev/abp-api/api/identity/roles/{any}`. I use the latest version of Ocelot (19.0.2). Isn't it possible that some bug has been introduced lately?

Comment: Same here {everything} does not work for me when I use empty {everything}, any solutions other than specifying separate route?

Comment: Look, the answer was valid in 2020, it'd be better to ask a new question for the latest version of Ocelot and include a link to this question if it helps provide context